# understanding format of file

Tags: c++, htk

I have a question regarding file reading and I am getting frustrated over it as I am doing some handwriting recognition development and the tool I am using doesn't seem to read my training data file.

So I have one file which works perfectly fine. I paste some contents of that file here:

```
 è      Aڈ2*A   ê“AêA mwA)àXA$NلAئ~A›إA:ozA)"ŒA%IœA&»ّAم3ACA

|®AH÷AD¢A ô-A گ&AJXAsAA mGA قQAٍALs@÷8´A
```

The file is in a format I know about that first 12 bytes are 2 longs and 2 shorts with most probably data as 4 , 1000 , 1024 , 9 but T cannot read the file to get these values.

Actually I want to write my first 12 bytes in format similar to the mentioned above and I dont seem to get how to do it.

Forgot to mention that the remaining data are float points. When I write data into file I get human readable text not these symbols and when I am reading these symbols I do not get the actual values. How to get the actual floats and integers across these symbols?

My code is

```
struct rec
{
    long a;
    long b ;
    short c;
    short d;
}; // this is the struct 

FILE *pFile;
struct rec my_record;

// then I read using fread

fread(&my_record,1,sizeof(my_record),pFile);`
```

and the values i get in `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are 85991456, -402448352, 8193, and 2336 instead of the actual values.

Comment: I am waiting ofcourse :)

Comment: The [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10671361/509303) was asked by you an hour earlier, wait for the answers instead of spamming questions.

Comment: yea but in that question i wasn't able to put up the question properly and there were way to many edits so i though it might be difficult for users to understand . but my bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should open that file in a hex editor, to see exactly what bytes it contains. From the text excerpt you have posted I think it does not contain 4, 1000, 1024 and 9 as you expect, but text form may be very misleading, because different character encodings show different characters for the same sequences of bytes.

If you have confirmed that the file contains the expected data, there may be still other issues. One of these is endianness, some machines and file formats encode a 4-byte `long` with least significant byte first, while others read and write the most significant byte first.

Other issue concerns the `long` data type you use. If your computer has a 64-bit architecture and you are using Linux, `long` is a 64-bit value, and your structure becomes 20 bytes long instead of 12.

**Edit:**

To read big-endian longs on a litte-endian machine like yours, you should read de data byte-by-byte and build the longs from them manually:

```
// Read 4 bytes
unsigned char buf[4];
fread(buf, 4, 1, pFile);
// Convert to long
my_record.a = (((long)buf[0]) << 24) | (((long)buf[1]) << 16) | (((long)buf[2]) << 8) | ((long)buf[3]);
```

Comment: I am using 64 bit machine with windows 7 . Okay so i opened it in Hex editor and if one box is equal to one byte then i have 1292 bytes in the file with first 12 bytes being 00 00 00 05 00 00 03 E8 01 00 00 09

When i posted my data here the spaces and few symbols got ommitted , Endian might be another issue how should i check it and secondly how to write integers into file so that it shows these symbols instead of actual values

Comment: and it should have 1292 bytes because there are 12 bytes for header and there there is sample of size 320 each of 4 bytes so totally it become 1292

Comment: sorry data should be 5 1000 1280 and 9 i believe

Comment: From this you can see that the problem is byte-endianness. 00 00 00 05 is 0x00000005 in hexadacimal, or 5 in decimal if you read it in big-endian order, but if you reverse the bytes, you get 0x05000000 in hexadecimal which is 83886080 in decimal. The same applies to the other values.

Comment: By the way, your expectation is wrong for the third value, your data is 0x00000005, 0x000003E8, 0x0100, 0x0009 which equals to 5, 1000, 256 and 9, respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother so the problem here is when i read the file it reads it into little endian because of my machine . So I shall write the file by changing endian to big endian . And one more query i can read first 12 bytes and that is valid . now next 4 bytes is supposed to be a decimal number ( float ) what i have in hex editor is 41 8F 32 2A , then next 4 bytes are 41 09 EA 93 .
What these two would be in decimal point of float numbers and how to convert them . Thanks a lot i am marking your answer as correct

Comment: Floats are a bit trickier, they cannot be easily converted from bytes to float using simple bit operations. I suppose you to read 4 bytes to the byte array, then reverse the order of bytes in the array. After this you can utilize some nasty pointer casts to get the float value from the byte array: `float f = *((float*)buf);`

Comment: hmm thanks and btw the code you gave for converting to long instead of converting the 4 bytes to 5 , converts it to 538976261

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11479/discussion-between-faisal-fayyaz-and-buc)

Answer (score 0):

Compiler adds padding to your structure members to make it (typically ) 4byte aligned. In this case variables `c` and `d` are padded.

You should read per-defined data types  at a time From your `fread` instead of your structure.

Comment: ok so what you are saying is i read into a long then a long and so on ? but the problem is fread doesnot seem to read anything logical let me try again and give u the result